# Measurability of a function on a measurable set

Tags: real-analysis

If $f^2$ is measurable on a measurable set $E$, is $f$ also measurable on $E$, also?

Answer (score 4):

We know there exists a nonmeasurable set, call it $A$, define

$$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : x \in A\\
       -1 & : x \notin A
     \end{array}
   \right. $$

Notice $f^{-1} ( [1, \infty) ) = A $ is non-meaasurable. But, $f^2 = 1 $ is obviously measurable.